# PopupPanel Not Showing

Tags: java, gwt, popup

It's late, I'm tired and I can't figure out why a simple popup panel instead of showing as it should, displays a label beneath my. For example:

```
|SOME CLICKABLE BUTTONS| |                         |
|SOME MORE OPTIONS     | |      SOME CONTENT       |
|EVEN MORE OPTIONS     | |                         |
|Please wait|
```

"Please wait" is the label as you can see is created like so in the:

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad()
{     ...<snip> //creates

        final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true);
        popup.add(new Label("Please wait"));
        popup.center();

        RootPanel.get().add(popup);
```

Some things you should know:

I'm running this in development mode via Jetty. I'm using reflections without class literals to load my panels because I haven't come round to implementing the workaround using generators (and the application is rather large, so it needs splitting). Though I doubt these things are causing it problems.

Shouldn't upon load, a popup display? My overall goal is to have something which displays a loading gif everytime a new part of the application is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add your PopupPanel to a RootPanel.

Delete this line

```
RootPanel.get().add(popup);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Ahh thankyou. My inability to follow instructions properly after too many hours working. Thankyou.